# Create a TypeScript project in Visual Studio Community 2019

Tags: typescript, visual-studio

Is there a way to create a TypeScript project in Visual Studio Community 2019?

All the tutorial I see are from previous version of Visual Studio--with its corresponding old version of the "New project" form. However, on 2019 I can't seem to find the option, even after adding the TypeScript components on the Visual Studio Installer.

Comment: I'm able to add TypeScript files to an existing project (Winforms, Class library, etc). So I "could" create an unrlated project and just add TypeScript files to it, but thet seems too dirty.

Comment: Actually one of the web projects is for angular so - that includes a full typescript setup, though a little odd one at times (i.e. using a global cli installation for angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the Project template manually.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Rich-Newman.TypeScriptHTMLApplicationTemplate&ssr=false#overview

Comment: Actually you do not ;) At least I find it in the already installed templates.